# Can I write mdc myself without IBM Cognos Transformer?

Tags: hadoop, business-intelligence, cognos, mdc

I want to use Hadoop/Mapreduce to product cube in Cognos MDC file, but it seems that mdc file can only product by Cognos Transformer?

so, can I write MDC file without Cognos Transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot to product cube youself, but if you want to use hadoop  ecosystem in congos BI, you can do something with congos Framework data source,or transformer data source. this may help you [Using Apache Hadoop in a Cognos BI environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505213/using-apache-hadoop-in-a-cognos-bi-environment)